# Can't get the 4th root using Newton-Raphson method

Tags: python, math, physics

I need to find the roots of the given equation using the N-R method. I am getting 3 of the 4 roots, but don't know why I am not able to get the last one. This is my code:

```
x = 1.5
for i in range(0,100):
    foX= ((6435)*x**8 - (12012)*x**6 + (6930)*x**4 - (1260)*x**2 + 35)/128
    devoX= ((6435*8)*x**7 - (12012*6)*x**5 + (6930*4)*x**3 - (1260*2)*x)/128

    delta = foX/devoX
    y = x - delta
    #print(y)
    error = abs(delta/x)
    if error<0.00000001:
        #print(y)
        print("{:.8f}".format(y))
        #break
        x=x-1/6
        continue
    x=y
```

Output:

```
0.96028986
0.79666648
0.52553241
-0.96028986
-0.96028986
-0.96028986
-0.96028986
-0.96028986
-0.96028986
-0.96028986
-0.96028986
-0.96028986
```

The actual roots are :

```
0.9602898564975, 0.7966664774136, 0.5255324099163, 0.1834346424957
```

If I change my initial condition from `x=1.5` to `x=1/6`, I get only the `0.1834346424957` root and not others.

I need a program that gives me all the 4(or 8) roots.

Comment: NR can be divergent depending on the initial point chosen. The roots you have found are correct (-0.96028986 is a root too), but they are only 4 of the possible 8. See [this chart](https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+%28%286435%29*x**8+-+%2812012%29*x**6+%2B+%286930%29*x**4+-+%281260%29*x**2+%2B+35%29%2F128) for a visualisation.

Comment: Choose initial point where tangent intersects X axis close to desired root then it should converge to the expected value. Avoid initial point where first derivative is small or null, it will send far away the next iteration. Newton method is an heuristic, there is no guarantee of convergence or stability.

Comment: So is there no way that I can get all the 4(or 8) roots using just one initial point?